# How to print the n-th elements of arrays with matching first items?

Tags: python

I am working in Python and I have the following data:

```
['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|256537', '819', '923']
['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|260076', '111', '189']
['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|260076', '4', '93']
['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238005', '258', '410']
['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238034', '606', '741']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|239209', '886', '1008']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238333', '1681', '1846']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238333', '1296', '1376']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238333', '1547', '1583']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|251903', '630', '722']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238005', '58', '209']
['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238034', '444', '553']
```

I need to print the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th items after matching first items like this:

```
DDX58_HUMAN gnl|CDD|256537 819 923 gnl|CDD|260076 111 189 gnl|CDD|260076 4 
93 gnl|CDD|238005 258 410 gnl|CDD|238034 606 741
DICER_HUMAN gnl|CDD|239209 886 1008 gnl|CDD|238333 1681 1846 gnl|CDD|238333 
1296 1376 gnl|CDD|238333 1547 1583 gnl|CDD|251903 630 722 gnl|CDD|238005 58 
209 gnl|CDD|238034 444 553
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do here. What do you mean with "matching first items?"

Comment: Perhaps you should say what you have tried, and why it doesn't meet your needs. SO people don't like to write code from scratch.

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for what you want to do :
I assume you have this data in python lists 
you can just traverse each list , and store values in a dictionary based on first element of the list and you will be able to get the unique entries.

```
mylist = [['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|256537', '819', '923']
,['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|260076', '111', '189']
,['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|260076', '4', '93']
,['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238005', '258', '410']
,['DDX58_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238034', '606', '741']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|239209', '886', '1008']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238333', '1681', '1846']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238333', '1296', '1376']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238333', '1547', '1583']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|251903', '630', '722']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238005', '58', '209']
,['DICER_HUMAN', 'gnl|CDD|238034', '444', '553']]

myDict = {}
for items in mylist :
    myDict.setdefault(items[0],[]).append(" ".join(x for x in items[1:]))

for k,v in myDict.items():

    print(k," : "," ".join(x for x in v))
```

**Output**

```
DDX58_HUMAN  :  gnl|CDD|256537 819 923 gnl|CDD|260076 111 189 gnl|CDD|260076 4 93 gnl|CDD|238005 258 410 gnl|CDD|238034 606 741
DICER_HUMAN  :  gnl|CDD|239209 886 1008 gnl|CDD|238333 1681 1846 gnl|CDD|238333 1296 1376 gnl|CDD|238333 1547 1583 gnl|CDD|251903 630 722 gnl|CDD|238005 58 209 gnl|CDD|238034 444 553
```

**If your data is in .txt file :**
Just read the text file and remove unwanted braces using `re` module and then same above mentioned logic will work.

```
import re
with open("data.txt") as mylist :

    myDict = {}
    mainList = []
    for items in mylist.readlines() :
        dataString = re.sub(r"[\[[\]]","",items.rstrip()).split(",")
        mainList.append(dataString)

myDict = {}
for items in mainList :
    myDict.setdefault(items[0],[]).append("".join(x for x in items[1:]))

for k,v in myDict.items():

    print(k," : ","".join(x for x in v))
```

**Output :**

```
'DICER_HUMAN'  :   'gnl|CDD|239209' '886' '1008' 'gnl|CDD|238333' '1681' '1846' 'gnl|CDD|238333' '1296' '1376' 'gnl|CDD|238333' '1547' '1583' 'gnl|CDD|251903' '630' '722' 'gnl|CDD|238005' '58' '209' 'gnl|CDD|238034' '444' '553'
'DDX58_HUMAN'  :   'gnl|CDD|256537' '819' '923' 'gnl|CDD|260076' '111' '189' 'gnl|CDD|260076' '4' '93' 'gnl|CDD|238005' '258' '410' 'gnl|CDD|238034' '606' '741'
```